# Docker shared folder with Linux

Tags: docker

Hello I have problem with sharing resources with docker.
I got folder

> Documents/Volume/

In folder Volume I have file data.txt
Now when I run image like this:

> docker run -v /Documents/Volume:/Volume -it busybox

I would expect that in folder Volume I will see file data.txt but file is missing.
So I create new file in folder Volume by command:

> echo "Hello world" > test.txt

Now I`m expecting that file test.txt is visible in /Documents/Volume/

Why I can't see files created in docker and from docker I can't see OS files?

Probably I'm missing something.

Comment: you need to pass full path to the folder like: `/var/share/Volume` but not just relative path you did just `Volume`. I use this trick when need relative path `-v $(pwd)/Volume:/data/Volume`

Comment: @Alex thanks. So I tried to share /var/Volume and everything was OK. Tried with /home/Documents/Volume/ and still not working. Can be problem with permissions? I'll try it. Thanks
Edit: Everything is working. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-v` volume parameter expects path to be absolute.

You need to pass full path to the folder like:

```
/var/share/Volume
```

but not just relative path you did just

```
Volume
```

I use this trick when need relative path

```
-v $(pwd)/Volume:/data/Volume
```