# Docker container not showing files in the shared volume

Tags: docker

I hope someone can help me to locate the issue. I created a SQL Server 2019 container using this code:

```
docker run --name SQL19 -p 1433:1433 -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=zzzzz258*" -v /SqlDockerVol/userdatabase:/userdatabase -v /SqlDockerVol/sqlbackups:/sqlbackups -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-lates
```

The problem I am having is the container not showing the files I saved in the `/sqlbackups` folder.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

I logged into the `SQL19` container like this:

```
docker exec -it  SQL19 /bin/bash
```

then issued `ls sqlbackups` to confirm.

Do I need to set any permission on the host folder. I am not familiar with Linux.

Thanks

Comment: So...the backups are in the host at /SqlDockerVol/sqlbackups  and you want to see them in the container at /sqlbackups or under currentDir/sqlBackups  ?

Comment: Does /SqlDockerVol/sqlbackups already exist on your Ubuntu host machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you need to pass absolute path to your folder:

```
/SqlDockerVol/userdatabase
```

is it full absolute path?

If it is relative change it to:

```
$(pwd)/SqlDockerVol/userdatabase
```

Please check this [Docker shared folder with Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51519365/docker-shared-folder-with-linux/51520101#51520101)

And technically you need something like:

```
docker run --name SQL19 -p 1433:1433 -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=zzzzz258*" -v $(pwd)/SqlDockerVol/userdatabase:/userdatabase -v $(pwd)/SqlDockerVol/sqlbackups:/sqlbackups -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-lates
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. Need to specify the absolute path as /home/user/SqlDockerVol.